# how to use conditions in telerik grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

I am having a telrik grid in my MVC 3.0 application. In grid I want to disable one of my column based on dates .

```
{Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.PostedDocument)
.Name("PostedDocumentsGrid")
.HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "grid scroll-pane" }) 
.Columns(columns =>
{
columns.Bound(o => o.DocumentLabel).Title(ResourceHelper.GetMessage("Posted_DocumentName")).Template(@<text><a href="@Url.Action("DownloadDocument", "ConsentAndDocument", new { documentId = @item.DocumentId })">@item.DocumentLabel</a></text>).Width(180)
```

I have a property in model which brings the expiray date from DB & if the expiry date is less or todays date has passed the expiry date (i.e DateTime.Now) then the link of the above column needs to be disabled or the data in that column(i.e links) needs to be disabled , it shud not get clicked

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.ClientTemplate("<#if(condition){#><a href=\"WaitingApprove/<#= LatestVersionId #>\">" + "if link" + "</a><# }
 else{#><a href=\"Edit/<#= Id #>\">" + "else link" + "</a> <# } #>")
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation to your answer, and/or include your code snippet within the code provided in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 cols.Bound(col => col.isAvailable)
      .ClientTemplate("<# if(isAvailable) { #> in stock <#} else { #> no <# } #>")
      .Title("Available")
      .HtmlAttributes(new { @title="Is available now?" });
```

This is working and tested example.